# NestJS: How to pass a service from a child to a parent?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, nestjs

In NestJS, I wish to have the same injected service in both parent class and child class.

#### Parent class

```js
export class ETH {
  constructor(
    @Inject('COIN_API_SERVICE')
    private readonly apiService: ClientProxy,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

#### Child class

```js
export class ERC20Token extends ETH {

  constructor(
    @Inject('COIN_API_SERVICE')
    private readonly apiService: ClientProxy,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

It gives the following error:

`TS2415: Class 'ERC20Token' incorrectly extends base class 'ETH'.   Types have separate declarations of a private property 'apiService'.`

But I need an instance of both, so both need to have an `apiService`. How to make sure both use the same instance of the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use a factory such that the factory is injected with all the dependencies. Consequently, the objects that are created through the factory.

The constructor of the factory would look somewhat like this:

```
constructor(
    @Inject('COIN_API_SERVICE')
    private readonly apiService: ClientProxy,
    coinType: CoinType,
) {
}
```

And then you can instantiate the coins using the injected API service and coin type.

If you only want to make the child constructor compile, you can have a look at the optional decorator: https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#optional-providers

Answer (score 2):

Make the origin class's `apiService` as protected:

```js
export class ETH extends Crypto {

  constructor(
    @Inject('COIN_API_SERVICE')
    protected readonly apiService: ClientProxy,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

And pass the service instance in super from child:

```js
export class ERC20Token extends ETH {

  constructor(
    @Inject('COIN_API_SERVICE')
    protected readonly apiService: ClientProxy,
  ) {
    super(apiService);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh it should be protected in child too

Answer (score 2):

Solution without passing services to *super* class:

```
class Parent {
    @Inject('COIN_API_SERVICE')
    protected readonly apiService: ClientProxy;

    // you can inject not only ClientProxy
    // but you should define it in module providers:
    // { provide: SomeService.name, useClass: SomeService }
    @Inject(SomeService.name)
    protected readonly someService: SomeService;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    // ...child logic
}
```